# How to play public web city camera video in android (using android studio)?

Tags: android, ip-camera

I want to create app to take video from public ip camera from city user choose.  For example, you write Rome and than you can watch video from one of public cameras from there. 
Here is my code for MediaPlayer from Android Studio and it is working only for address that has .mp4 in the end(addres from example below is not working because of the end of it), I do not understand why. I need to play video from real time public city web cams.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String urlStr = "http://www.hf.uio.no/iakh/english/studies/blog/video/mov_0381.mp4?vrtx=view-as-webpage";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlStr);

        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        vv.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {return false;}
        });
        try {vv.setVideoURI(uri);} catch (Exception e) {}
        try {vv.start();} catch (Exception e) {}
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(null);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This might get downvoted for being too broad or soliciting opinion-based answers. Maybe break the problem down. Start without the map, just get a list of a few cameras to appear, click one and start the web streaming. [VLC Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html) might be a good place to see how you can stream video from a server to an Android platform (it's open source, too).

Comment: Thx, where can i take an ip cams stream? How url should look like?  For example can it be like this https://www.insecam.org/en/view/641563/

Comment: Personally, I’ve only done this once and it was a while ago. Download VLC for your computer, then follow the [manual](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/). You should be able to try out the url easy enough without coding anything.

Comment: I tried to use MediaPlayer, it should work for all formats as I understand. But it doesn't.